# websocket server can't find class mysqli. How can i use mysql database connection inside my own websocket server?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wanna use mysqli database connection inside my own websocket server. How can i use the database without defining the unix socket path? Like this:
`$connection = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name,3306,'/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock');`

The webSocket server is running on `localhost:8080`. I also tried some other ports and hostnames but i got stil the same error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in D:\project\`

```
$this->socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($this->socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($this->socketResource, 0, $this->port);
socket_listen($this->socketResource);
```

```
public function connectToDatabase(){
      $db_servername = "localhost";
      $db_username = "root";
      $db_password = "root";
      $db_name = "dbname";

      // Create connection
      $connection = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
      return $connection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the class doesn't exist, which you don't have the mysqli extension installed. [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)

Personally I don't use Windows but if I remember correctly you should go to your php.ini file and uncomment the line extension=mysqli. (I don't know if this is the actual name but doing a mysqli search should get you where you have be.). The binaries are usually already installed on Windows, but if they aren't you should be able to find a downloadable from the PHP manual.

Comment: I have the same problem on my macbook pro aswel. When i connect with the database without my webSocket then it is working fine.

Comment: Do you have the mysqli extension installed? @Carpiee

Comment: How can i check that on windows or mac os?

Comment: @Carpiee phpinfo(), search for mysqli if you cannot find it under extensions it means it's not installed

Comment: there is a part of `mysqli support`. i can't find that it is says `not supported`

Comment: Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Does it say enabled?

Comment: If the class doesn't exists it means the extension isn't loaded or you might be in a namespace and are not importing the mysqli class

Comment: it says that mysqlnd is enabled. what would be the namespace then?

Comment: Client API library version mysqlnd 7.4.12
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links 0
Active Links 0

Comment: Not `mysqlnd` thats a different extension `mysqli`.

Comment: If you cannot find it it means it is uninstalled

Comment: these settings are in the mysqli table:  
Client API library version mysqlnd 7.4.12
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links 0
Active Links 0

Comment: I'm sorry but you said "it says that mysqlnd is enabled." Which tells me you see `mysqlnd => enabled` in the CLI output. But you should also find `MysqlI Support => enabled` somewhere if you don't it means the extension is NOT installed.

Comment: But if you thing it is the namespace thing prefix the `new mysqli` with `new \mysqli`

Comment: yes `MysqlI Support => enabled` this one is in the top of the table

Comment: I also added the forward slash `\mysqli`

Comment: Sorry I can't help you!